# jQuery first click show() second loads video

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer

I have a jw player where the link click changes the video. I also have other type of players so I need to hide jw player and switch to youtube player. The problem is that the jw player loads the video on second click afte the video player is visible. Any solution so that the player loads the video on first click.

```
<div id="jw_container">       
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://content.jwplatform.com/players/hsdfQtN-ieOuTCiv.js"></script>
</div>

<li><a href="javascript:playTrailer('Bmodfg5AS')" id="vid_link3">video</a></li>

function playTrailer(key) {
    $('#jw_container').show(); // show video player        
    jwplayer().load("https://content.bitsontherun.com/jw6/" + key + ".xml");
    jwplayer().play({
        autostart: false
    });
}
```

as you can see, first click make the video visible and second load the specific video. There is one solution to this and instead of using show(); to use .css('visibility','visible') but that causes some css issues.

The actual code:

```
var loaded = false;
    function playTrailer(key) {   
      $('#yt_container').hide();    // hide youtube  
      $('#jw_container').show("slow", function() {    
        jwplayer().load("https://content.bitsontherun.com/jw6/" + key + ".xml");        
        });
        loaded = true;
    }
    jwplayer().onPlaylistItem(function() {
      if(loaded) {    
        jwplayer().play({autostart:false});
      }
    })
```

Comment: what if you make autostart to true?

Comment: nothing, the same thing happens. Actually autostart doesn't even change anything, weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you need is to set

**EDIT**

```
 $('#jw_container').show(0,'', function() {
    // Animation complete.
jwplayer().load("https://content.bitsontherun.com/jw6/" + key + ".xml");
jwplayer().play(true);
  });
```

Hypothetically it might be that the playlist is not loaded so the play method is being executed on nothing. So this might also work:

```
function playTrailer(key) {
     $('#jw_container').show(); // show video player        
        jwplayer().load("https://content.bitsontherun.com/jw6/" + key + ".xml");
    jwplayer().onPlaylist( function(event){
        jwplayer().play(true);
      });
    }
```

Comment: sorry, that didn't help.

Comment: @SamotnyPocitac try the edited version and if that doesn't work I have one more idea.

Comment: still nothing. It looks like it needs some time to load it. Maybe instead of slow some nice fade out will do the job. What do you think?

Comment: @SamotnyPocitac that's interesting behavior give my second block of code a try and see if that does anything.

Comment: I noticed that it doesn't always work. It looks like the script doesn't make it all the time.

Comment: the second block of code is the actual code I'm using.

Comment: I edited the code in the question. It works with the "slow" but it has the slow motion plus sometime it doesn't load it properly but mostly it works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47450/discussion-between-thunda-and-samotnypocitac)

Comment: @SamotnyPocitac That is interesting so my second block didn't do anything? It also is different then your updated code because it is using onPlaylist not PlaylistItem. One more thing is that "autostart" is not a property according to the API of jwplayer.